# PHP taking much longer to perform query than MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Now I must start by saying, I can't copy the string.  This is a general question.

I've got a query with several joins in that takes 0.9 seconds when run using the mysql CLI.  I'm now trying to run the same query on a PHP site and it's taking 8 seconds.  There are some other big joins on the site that are obviously slower, but this string is taking much too long.  Is there a PHP cache for database connections that I need to increase?  Or is this just to be expected.

Comment: 8 seconds is a lot of time, and not the be expected. You are definitely doing something wrong. Post the query here, along with the output from `explain select`.

Comment: Query time depends on what were running at the server that time. Can you please tell that the server was not running anything at both times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP doesn't really do much with MySQL; it sends a query string to the server, and processes the results. The only bottleneck here is if it's an absolutely *vast* query string, or if you're getting a lot of results back - PHP has to cache and parse them into an object (or array, depending on which `mysql_fetch_*` you use). Without knowing what your query or results are like, I can only guess.

---

(From comments): If we have 30 columns and around, say, a million rows, this will take an *age* to parse (we later find that it's only 10k rows, so that's ok). You need to rethink how you do things:-

- See if you can reduce the result set. If you're paginating things, you can use `LIMIT` clauses.
- Do more in the MySQL query; instead of getting PHP to sort the results, let MySQL do it by using `ORDER BY` clauses.
- Reduce the number of columns you fetch by explicitly specifying each column name instead of `SELECT * FROM ...`.

Comment: Results are pretty big, there are 30 columns and 10000k+ rows (which are then sorted).  I think it's the building the array in PHP that's taking the time.

Comment: Please see my edits. Can you post a little more detail about what the end-application for this query is? Also, surely you can't mean 10,000 _thousand_ rows can you? That's a rather large database. Do you mean 10k rows?

Comment: Sorry, I did mean 10k rows.  But the results are then limited using LIMIT and ordered using ORDER BY, I thought you meant the contents of the original table.

Comment: The odd thing is, when I profile the query, it looks fine.

starting  0.000040
Opening tables  0.000045
System lock  0.000003
Table lock  0.000006
init  0.000010
optimizing  0.000005
statistics  0.000010
preparing  0.000010
executing  0.000025
Sending data  0.000024
end  0.000003
end  0.000003
query end  0.000002
freeing items  0.000003
closing tables  0.000003
removing tmp table  0.000006
closing tables  0.000002
logging slow query  0.000003
cleaning up  0.000002

Comment: In that case, it could be your hardware, although 10k rows is still a huge amount to be passing to PHP. In response to your latest comment, that is very strange indeed - I can't see anything that takes any noticeable amount of time. This _does_ show that it's going to be PHP, or the connection between the MySQL and PHP servers, if you have them separate.

Comment: I'm limiting to 50.  So PHP should only see 50.  I thought there would be a cache setting somewhere that could be increased.

Comment: Me too! It's strange.  I can only think it's holding while parsing to PHP.  I can write it another way (building several arrays with just SELECTS with no joins) but this makes manipulation a bit harder.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Some wild guesses:

The PHP-version uses different parameters and variables each query: MySQL cannot cache it. While the version you type on the MySQL-CLI uses the same parameter: MySQL can fetch it from its cache. Try adding the `SQL_NO_CACHE` to your query on CLI to see if the result requires more time.

You are not testing on the same machine? Is the MySQL database you test the PHP-MySQL query with and the CLI the same machine? I mean: you are not testing one on your laptop and the other one on some production server, are you?

You are testing over a network: When the MySQL server is not installed on the same host as your PHP app, you will see some MySQL connection that uses "someserver.tld" instead of "localhost" as database host. In that case PHP will need to connect over a network, while your CLI already has that connection, or connects only local.

The actual connection is taking a long time. Try to run and time the query from your PHP-system a thousand times after each other. Instead of "connect to server, query database, disconnect", you should see the query timing when it is "connect to server, query database thousand times, disconnect". Some PHP-applications do that: they connect and disconnect for each and every query. And if your MySQL server is not configured correctly, connecting can take a gigantic amount of the total time.

Comment: I can run the site on localhost (Apache, PHP and MySQL are all on the same box) and it still takes 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

How are you timing it?

If the 'long' version is accessed through a php page on a website, could the additional 7.1 seconds not just be the time it takes to send the request and then process and render the results?

Comment: printing a timestamp before the query and after so the rest of the page load time doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting? Does the account you're using use a hostname in the `grant` tables? If you're connectinv via TCP, MySQL will have to do a reverse DNS lookup on your IP to figure out if you're allowed in.

If it's the connection causing this, then do a simple test:

```
select version();
```

if that takes 8seconds, then it's connection overhead. If it return instantly, then it's PHP overhead in processing the data you've fetched.

Comment: I have many other queries on the site that take 0.01 seconds.

Comment: Easy enough to check that too. if it's PHP overhead, then the while() loop to fetch the data will take the longest amount of time. do a `microtime(true)` call before/after the query call and before/after the fetch loop. That'll get you the total time needed for both.

Answer (score 0):

The function mysql_query should should take the same time as mysql client. But any extra mysql_fetch_* will add up.